binary constant value in PL/1
Below is a binary constant declaration in Mainframe PL/1. Please tell me how to calculate the numeric value in WAVE_LTH.
*DCL WAVE_LTH  FLOAT BINARY (21)

WAVE_LTH=11001E-10B*

